# Why do some tasks in Gradle not show up as properties?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to make one of the *default* gradle tasks depend on a custom task (to do some work before the default task kicks in), but the `dependsOn` construct doesn't seem to work for *every* task available. For example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.android.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        PlayStore {
        }
        Amazon {
        }
    }
}

task info << {
    println "Hello, Gradle"
}

// following dependsOn works just fine
assembleDebug.dependsOn info

// following line (uncommented) will cause error
//assembleAmazonDebug.dependsOn info

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

The `assembleDebug` works just fine in the example but uncomment the `assembleAmazonDebug` line and you get an error message:

> Could not find property 'assembleAmazonDebug' on project ':app'.

`gradlew tasks --all` produces a long list of tasks, many of which can't be used with the dependsOn construct.

Is there some key difference between tasks where some can be used as properties and some cannot?

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because some tasks are created during script evaluation, hence they are not available at configuration time but at runtime only. I'm not sure about syntax (and if it's possible to define dependency at this level od evaluation) but try:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
   assembleAmazonDebug.dependsOn info
}
```

It will define the dependency just after all the plugins are applied and all the tasks are created.

Comment: Excellent -- did not know about afterEvaluate -- thanks, Opal!